# Variable in XPath select to avoid code duplication

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I'd like to represent an XPath expression in an XSL variable (or use another technique) and then use that stored expression multiple XSLT select parameters. (The XPath expression is complicated and I would like to define/maintain it in one place.)

I'm using msxsl, which uses XSL 1.0.

In the following working example code I'd like to avoid duplication of "@attr1 != 'aaa' and @attr1 != 'bbb'".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <results>
        <xsl:for-each select="//node[@attr1 != 'aaa' and @attr1 != 'bbb']">
            <result-node parent="AAA">
                <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
            </result-node>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:for-each select="//node[@attr1 != 'aaa' and @attr1 != 'bbb']">
            <result-node parent="BBB">
                <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
            </result-node>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </results>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Here is a sample XML followed by the output when processed with the above code.

XML:

```
<root>
    <AAA>
        <node attr1="aaa" value="1"/>
        <node attr1="bbb" value="2"/>
        <node attr1="ccc" value="3"/>
        <node attr1="ddd" value="4"/>
    </AAA>
    <BBB>
        <node attr1="aaa" value="5"/>
        <node attr1="bbb" value="6"/>
        <node attr1="ccc" value="7"/>
        <node attr1="ddd" value="8"/>
    </BBB>
</root>
```

Output:

```
<results>
   <result-node parent="AAA">3</result-node>
   <result-node parent="AAA">4</result-node>
   <result-node parent="AAA">7</result-node>
   <result-node parent="AAA">8</result-node>
   <result-node parent="BBB">3</result-node>
   <result-node parent="BBB">4</result-node>
   <result-node parent="BBB">7</result-node>
   <result-node parent="BBB">8</result-node>
</results>
```

Comment: Please add an input XML to your question, as well as the output you expect. It might not be necessary to store an XPath expression in a variable at all - we need to know [what you are really trying to achieve](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKw6/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable stores the result of evaluating an expression - not the expression itself.

To achieve your goal of avoiding code duplication, consider creating a filtered node-set first, then applying *predicates* to select a sub-set - for example:

```
<xsl:variable name="my-set" select= "node[@attr1!='aaa' and @attr1!='bbb']" />
```

and:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$my-set[parent::AAA]">
```

Comment: Hi Michael, I tried for a while but could not get that to work. Don't know why; seemed like the parent:: just was not working. I've edited my question with fully functioning code to more exactly demonstrate what I'm trying to do, in case it was earlier not clear.

Comment: @CaptainNormal I already gave you a full, working example of Michael's solution - as a comment on your question: http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKw6/2. You absolutely do not need to call templates.

Comment: Hi Mathias, you (and Michael) are perfectly correct. I've adjusted the question back to match what it originally was and to match your excellent example. My current problem is still not 100% resolved, but the remaining problem is off-topic so I'll post it separately. Thank you.